# Control.begininvoke(delegate,object[]) is very slow

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am using the following method

**control.BeginInvoke(delegate,object[])**

where control is System.Windows.Forms.Control class

I am using the above method for **updating the image** but images are not being updated properly. Sometimes **it is hanging or sometime it updates very late**.

So how can I use it in sync with other object of the form?
I am using C# windows form and Framework 3.5.

In form there are some text boxes and for each textboxes images are being updated.
and if all the field of a form is visited then it moves to next form and so on...

But some times it is not updating according to that. and it is updating very late.

**Suppose I am on form no. 50 but image is being refreshed for form no. 20.**

**or sometimes it is hanging and images are not being updated.**

I am using MSMQ for each form. If my MSMQ name is ABC in private queues the it will have 100 documents for 100 forms.

Actually it is not 100 or 1000 form. It is only one form and clicking next it loaded document for next MSMQ in same form but with data and images of next form.

Comment: The question is not clear...  How do you use it (where? how often?)? What image is being updated?

Comment: 50 forms? How long do you think the message will take to get through the message bus?

Comment: Could you show relevant peace of code? Why are you using `BeginInvoke`  (updating form20 image from form50 doesn't really need invoking)?

Comment: I am not invoking form20 image from form50. on each tab it is being called. and if I go to form 50 till then it was not able to process data of form20 and it is keeping remaining 30 form data in pool.and when I stop tabbing(moving to next field) then after some time it is being updated in sync.

Comment: winforms is slow. If you want more performance use current technology instead. BTW, post the relevant code.

Comment: I welcome all the suggestions. But the product on which I am working is a stable product and running successfully from 5-6 yrs and having  turnout in millions $. I am using .net framework 3.5 and I cannot change the framework because it lead to change a lot.